# Elasticsearch nodeJS - search query with sum/subtract of nested values

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to perform a `sum` in my `search` query, on (number) nested fields (array of object)

My data represent a list of object, and for every object I have a nested list of `start/end` timestamp that represent every visits

my data looks like that :

```
[
  {
    title: '',
    ...,
    visits: //nested
      [
        {
          start: 1617700260000,
          end: 1617700280000
        },
        {
          start: 1617700260001,
          end: 1617700280001
        }, ...
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

If I use a `aggregate` the query works but the aggregate is done on the total and not on every document.

I would like to have a new field that contains the subtract of every `visists.end` - `visits.start` to have the total amount

so I tried :

```
      await client.search({
        index: 'myIndex',
        body: {
          script_fields: {
            total_time: {
              script: {
                source: "doc['visits']['end'].value - doc['visits']['start'].value",
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```

But I continue to have errors and I can't manage to do it,

```
ResponseError: search_phase_execution_exception
```

without more information

I imagine that the script must handle the fact that the nested object is an array, but I can't manage to go further that this error

IF I replace the source of the script by just returning a flat value, it's ok
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work like that :

```
      await client.search({
        index: 'myIndex',
        body: {
          _source: true, // to see the srouce object in the response
          script_fields: {
            total_time: {
              script: {
              lang: 'painless',
              source:
                "def total = 0; for (def i = 0; i < params['_source']['visits'].size(); i++) { total += params['_source']['visits'][i].end - params['_source']['visits'][i].start; } return total;",
            },
            },
          },
        },
      });
```